# Java testing initializationError : java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

Tags: java

My project is composed like this

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjbt5.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttx3W.png

when i try to run the tests the error

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
 at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
 at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
 at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
```

presents itself.

I have downloaded the right libraries for junit-4 and i believe it has something to do with how the project is built because when i tried to do a test on another simpler project it worked.
Maybe I have made a mistake in how I divided my space for my project or maybe I forgot some options on my settings.json file which I'll link down here [settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjbt5.png)

I'll also link my test project which could help identify the problem but it's very messy and unorganized so thanks to anyone that takes the time to help me

```
package test;

public class DemoApplicationTest {

    public static DemoApplication.Logs Log;
    private static final String Server = "dw.gnet.it", user = "unimore22", pass = "weblog";
    private static final int port = 21;
    

    /*
      Test del metodo pulizia che controlla se vengono rimpiazzate tutte le istanze
      previste dal codice quali | [ | ] | ( | ) | \ | ; | , | + |
    */
    @Test    
    public void Testpulizia() {
    String valore = "A[B]C(D)E\"F;G,H+I";

        valore = valore.replace("[", "");
        valore = valore.replace("]", "");
        valore = valore.replace("(", "");
        valore = valore.replace(")", "");
        valore = valore.replace("\"", "");
        valore = valore.replace(";", "");
        valore = valore.replace(",", "");
        valore = valore.replace("+", "");
        valore = valore.toLowerCase();
        assertEquals("ProvoLaStringa","ABCDEFGHI", valore.toString().toUpperCase());
    }

    /* 
        Test che controlla se il modulo LetturaFile riesce a leggere 
        un file di testo demo 
    */
    @Test
    public  void TestLetturaFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/output.txt"));
        String NomeFile = "/output.txt";
        JSONArray ja = DemoApplication.LetturaFile(sc, NomeFile);

        assertEquals("NomeFileRighe:output.txt"+"-", ja);
    }

    /*
        Test del modulo di FTPDownload dove si controlla se viene ritornato
        true se si riesce a recuperare il file e a scriverlo sull' outputstream
    */
    @Test
    public void TestFTPDownload() throws SocketException, IOException {
       String File = new String();
       OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
       FTPClient ftp = DemoApplication.ConnectionFTP(Server, user, pass, port);
       boolean successo = false;
        try{
            successo = ftp.retrieveFile(File, os);
            os.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            fail("Unexpected exeption was thrown");
        }
            assertEquals(true , successo);
    }

    /*
        Test che controlla se il modulo ConnectionFTP riesce a connettersi a un
        qualsiasi server ritornado true.
    */
    @Test
    public void TestConnectionFTP() {
        String server  ="test.rebex.net";
        String user = "demo";
        String pass = "password";
        int port = 21;
        FTPClient ftp = DemoApplication.ConnectionFTP(server, user, pass, port);
        assertEquals(true, ftp);
    }


    /*
        Test che controlla se il modulo procedura funziona controllando
        se il return di procedura ritorna true
    */
    @Test
    public void TestProcedura() throws FileNotFoundException {

        FTPClient ftp = DemoApplication.ConnectionFTP(Server, user, pass, port);
        boolean scaricato = DemoApplication.Procedura(ftp);
    
        assertEquals(true, scaricato);
            
        
    }   

}
```

Comment: The root problem is that the class uses an annotation that is missing at runtime. The secondary problem is that you stumbled across [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7183985). The solution, however, is to solve the root problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see that I didn't include my dependencies in the code but I found the annotation that messed up everything.